# Power BI distinct users for distinct applications

Tags: powerbi

my table is like given below

APP NAME     USER ID
APP_A                  P1001
APP_A                  P1002
APP_A                  P1003
APP_A                  P1004
APP_B                  P1001
APP_B                  P1002
APP_B                  P1003
APP_C                  P1001
APP_C                  P1002
APP_C                  P1004
APP_D                  P1001
APP_D                  P1002
APP_D                  P1004
APP_D                  P1005

need result like, common users from all applications

Sample result

APP NAME      USER ID
APP_A                   P1001
APP_A                   P1002
APP_B                   P1001
APP_B                   P1002
APP_C                   P1001
APP_C                   P1002
APP_D                   P1001
APP_D                   P1002

SUMMARIZE function did not help

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand actually what is your question but you have to transform your data and on the transform data tab you can check the value of columns and get the desired result.

Comment: Hv modified now

Comment: I did not  get you please can you explain?